# Django, usar CreateView trayendo un valor de un campo de una tabla

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

Como parte de un proyecto para un curso que estoy haciendo, estoy programando una apliación web para una libreria online. El mismo tiene un sistema de reseñas, y necesito ayuda en algo.
Al ingresar en el detalle de un libro, listo las reseñas de ese libro y quiero llamar a una función CreateView para crear una nueva reseña de ese libro. Pero no se como llamar a esa función para que me tome el valor del campo Book que estoy viendo.
Mi archivo views.py tiene la funcion de listar los detalles del libro y crear nueva reseña.

```
class BookDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Book

class AddReview(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.CreateView):
    model = Review
    fields = ('comment','rating',)
    success_url = reverse_lazy('list-reviews')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user_name =  self.request.user 
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

En models.py tengo mis tablas

```
class Review(models.Model):
    RATING_CHOICES = (
        (1, '1'),
        (2, '2'),
        (3, '3'),
        (4, '4'),
        (5, '5'),
    )
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, null = True, on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING, verbose_name = 'Libro')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,verbose_name = 'Fecha de publicacion')
    user_name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null = True, blank = True)
    comment = models.TextField(verbose_name = 'Reseña')
    rating = models.IntegerField(choices=RATING_CHOICES,verbose_name = 'Clasificación')

    def get_absolute_url(self):

        return reverse('review-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

class Book(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(verbose_name = 'Titulo', max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name = 'Autor')     
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=1000, 
        help_text="Ingrese una breve descripción del libro", verbose_name = 'Resumen')  
    isbn = models.CharField('ISBN',max_length=13,
        help_text='13 Caracteres <a href="https://www.isbn-international.org/content/what-isbn">ISBN number</a>')
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, 
        help_text="Seleccione los generos de este libro", verbose_name = 'Genero')
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, verbose_name = 'Lenguaje')
```

La función AddReview la llamo dentro del html del detalle del libro que es el siguiente:

```
<p><strong>Autor:</strong> <a href="{{ book.author.get_absolute_url }}">{{ book.author }}</a></p>
    <p style="width: 1000px;"><strong>Resumen:</strong> {{ book.summary }}</p>
    <h6><strong>ISBN:</strong> {{ book.isbn }}</h6>
    <h6>
      <strong>Clasificacion:</strong> {{ book.average_rating }} de 5 
      **<a href="{% url 'add-review' %}">Nueva reseña</a>**
    </h6>
    <h6><strong>Lenguaje:</strong> {{ book.language }}</h6>
    <h6><strong>Genero:</strong> {% for genre in book.genre.all %} {{ genre }}{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}{% endfor %}</h6><br>
```

Aqui es donde necesito que al llamar a AddReview, y de alguna manera pasar el campo book de Book donde estoy viendo ese libro, al campo book de Review.
Agradezco desde ya quien pueda ayudarme con esto
Saludos

Comment: No te entiendo muy bien lo que quieres hacer, pero quieres que por defecto al crearse una instancia en la vista `AddReview` se relacione con un libro en especifico, sin necesidad de seleccionarlo?

Comment: Hola estimado, es eso exactamente. Al crear una instancia con AddReview, necestio que el campo Book no sea necesario seleccionarlo. AddReview la llamo desde un template que me está mostrando los detalles de un Libro

Comment: Ok, ya publique mi respuesta, échale un vistaso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que quieres lograr según me comentaste es que al crear una instancia del modelo `Review` con la vista `AddReview`, necesitas que el campo `book` no se necesario seleccionarlo. Pero si no le vamos a dar la opción de seleccionar al usuario (que debería ser asi), entonces no es necesario mostrar dicho campo, lo mas optimo seria no mostrar el campo y que la vista se encargue de dar un valor a dicho campo.

Para eso necesitamos modificar la URL de la vista `AddReview`, para que reciba como argumento el `id` o `pk` del libro, de la siguiente manera:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('addreview/<int:book_pk>/', AddReview.as_view(), name = 'add-review')
    ...
]
```

En la vista nos encargaremos de obtener el libro del cual queremos crear la reseña y asignamos dicho libro a la relación `book` del modelo `Review`:

```
class AddReview(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.CreateView):
    model = Review
    fields = ('comment','rating',)
    success_url = reverse_lazy('list-reviews')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Obtenemos el libro
        book = Book.objects.get(pk = self.kwargs.get('book_pk'))

        form.instance.user_name =  self.request.user
        form.instance.book = book # Le asignamos el libro a la relacion book del modelo review 

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Y listo, al momento de generar la URL de la vista `AddReview` asegúrate de pasarle como argumento el `id` o el `pk` del libro (Como estamos en una `DetailView` no habrá problema):

```
<a href="{% url 'add-review' book.pk %}">Nueva reseña</a>
```

No sera necesario mostrar el campo `book` en el form, pues en la vista ya se le asignara un libro en especifico a la relación `book`(`Review`). De esta manera solo sera necesario pasarle el id del libro a la vista y la vista ya se encargara de todo.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Anduvo perfecto. Estuve bastantes horas con esto y nunca lo hubiese podido resolver. Ya acepté tu respuesta.

Comment: Un gusto poder ayudarte!